# draw three circles as zones covering map of india on leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to create three zones on India map showing hazard factors. The three zones should be represented by three circles.The Circle drawn on leaflet map seems to resize and becomes more smaller on changing the zoom level.Is there any solution to draw circle of constant size. this code doesnt work for me.

```
var circle = L.circleMarker([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
var myZoom = {
  start:  map.getZoom(),
  end: map.getZoom()
};

map.on('zoomstart', function(e) {
   myZoom.start = map.getZoom();
});

map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
    myZoom.end = map.getZoom();
    var diff = myZoom.start - myZoom.end;
    if (diff > 0) {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 2);
    } else if (diff < 0) {
        circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() / 2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just remove the 'zoomend' function